# Open transparent activity and take a screenshot

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-bitmap

I want to take a screenshot of the current screen of the device (without rooting). So I am opening a transparent activity to take a screenshot so that I can get the screenshot of the current device screen. But I am getting error as mentioned below.

P.S: I am able to get the screenshot image if I put the `takeScreen()` method inside the MainActivity class. But I don't want that.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    }

    public void btn_1(View view) {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, transparentActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}
```

**transparentActivity.java**

```
public class transparentActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.transparent_layout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Bitmap image = takeScreen();
    }

    public Bitmap takeScreen() {
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

**main_layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_marginStart="235dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="99dp"
        android:onClick="btn_1"
        android:text="Button 1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**transparent_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity
    android:name=".transparentActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

I am getting the below error when I am running the code.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{transparentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: "I want to take a screenshot of the current screen of the device" -- use [the media projection APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary) on Android 5.0+. "So I am opening a transparent activity to take a screenshot so that I can get the screenshot of the current device screen" -- your approach will not work.

Comment: Your View v1 is just the view of your transparent activity. Since it is transparent, the resulting 'screenshot' will also be transparent. As for your error, it is a pretty self-explanatory NullPointerException. You should read what it says.

Comment: You are trying to do this too early. In `onStart()` the `View` hierarchy has not yet been set up. You should wrap your call to `takeScreen()` inside a `Runnable` and post that to run after a short delay (1 second).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will not take screenshot of the screen behind your transparent activity as this method only saves the content of the perticular view or layout not what you actually see on the screen.

So please try using Media Projection APIs - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary as suggested in comments.

For error part, please click on the error message in the android studio - this will take cursor to the line where error is occurring and hopefully you can come to conclusion quickly.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting that error because you are trying to get activity width and height before activity finish. You need to trigger it after activity is done, with an invisible button or something else.

By the way, you can't use life cycle to trigger your screenshot action because I already try it and give the same error like you. And as note even it can take screenshot the result will be black and I don't know why, but my thought is because activity it self even we can see it as transparent.